# Spock Prime In Alternate Universe

Tags: star-trek

When Spock Prime meets Kirk he recognizes him immediately. How does he know it's him since Chris Pine looks nothing Bill Shatner?

Comment: Due to the magic power of recasting :-P

Comment: It's called "suspension of disbelief". You'd think he'd be equally surprised that his younger self looks like an entirely different person.

Comment: Well, to be fair, Captain Kirk may look nothing like Bill Shatner either. Shatner just played him on TV.

Answer (score 1):

Diagretically, the character played by Chris Pine looks exactly like the young Kirk, because he is the young Kirk.

The extent to which the actor can carry this off is a matter for the individual film goer who may or may not have seen William Shatner play Kirk (unless the movie is a meta one involving fourth wall breaking, it can not be the concern of the character played by Leonard Nimoy within the movie).